# How to fix MySql database restore error using Wordpress UpdraftPlus: Error Code: 1067. Invalid default value for 'user_registered'

Tags: mysql, wordpress

When running my Wordpress UpdraftPlus database restore script I get the error `Error Code: 1067. Invalid default value for 'user_registered'`

I tried prefixing the script with

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode = 'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
drop database wordpress;
create database wordpress;
use wordpress;
```

as suggested here: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/invalid-default-value-database-install-fail/ but it doesn't make a difference.

The part of the script giving the error is 
`CREATE TABLE`wp_users`(`ID`bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,`user_login`varchar(60) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',`user_pass`varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',`user_nicename`varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',`user_email`varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',`user_url`varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',`user_registered`datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',`user_activation_key`varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',`user_status`int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',`display_name`varchar(250) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',   PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),   KEY`user_login_key`(`user_login`),   KEY`user_nicename`(`user_nicename`),   KEY`user_email`(`user_email`) ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html),

> Setting the GLOBAL variable requires the SUPER privilege and affects the operation of all clients that connect from that time on. Setting the SESSION variable affects only the current client.

So to just create your table, either reconnect or set the session variable.

But both ways will only have temporary affect, because after a server restart, your settings will be reset to the default values, and you won't be able to insert new users to the table anymore.

So after you tested the setting, you will have to set the value in your config file (e.g. `my.cnf`). You should also only remove the option that is causing you trouble, which is either the depreciated [`NO_ZERO_DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_zero_date) or [`STRICT_TRANS_TABLES`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_strict_trans_tables).

So for a 5.7.8+ default configuration, add under `[mysqld]`

```
sql_mode='ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'
```

to your config file and restart your server.

For MySQL 5.7.4 to 5.7.7, you would have to remove the `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` instead, because `NO_ZERO_DATE` has no affect (and will have no affect again in some future version).

You might have to remove further options, a usual suspect is often `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`, but only remove it if you run into problems with wordpress.

Comment: Thanks, using this worked: `SET SESSION sql_mode = 'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';`